# Use DatePicker to filter DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datepicker

I have a DataTable named 'search_table' in my page. I have a additional header row in the table that has different filter options (dropdown, text, date_pickers). For the date columns, I have two datepickers, one for min and one for max. I can filter the data for the datatable based on the datepickers, but there is one problem:

When I select a date, all the rows in my table disappear, I have to click on one of the headers (like to sort the data) to get the data to appear. Once I do so, the correct data shows (the dates are between min and max).

What functionality do I use to force the datapicker to re-draw the table? In my ready function, I have the following code:

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
      var table = $('#search_table').DataTable();
      $(".datepicker").datepicker( {
          maxDate:0,
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
          onClose: function(selectedDate) {
              table.draw();}});
      $('#min_create, #max_create, #min_update, #max_update').keyup(function() { table.draw(); });
      $('#min_create, #max_create, #min_update, #max_update').click( function() { table.draw(); });
      $('#min_create').datepicker().bind('onClose', function(){ table.draw(); });
  });
```

min_create, max_create, min_update and max_update are all inputs that have the datepicker class. search_table is my table that is a DataTable.

Comment: have you tried clearing the datatable before calling the table.draw() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had two issues that when fixed solved my problem.

In my ready function, I had

```
var table = $('#search_table').DataTable();
```

this should have been

```
var table = $('#search_table').dataTable();
```

Then, in the code for the datepicker class I had

```
  $(".datepicker").datepicker( {
      maxDate:0,
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      onClose: function(selectedDate) {
          table.draw();}});
```

and it needs to be changed to

```
  $(".datepicker").datepicker( {
      maxDate:0,
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      onClose: function(selectedDate) {
          table.fnDraw();}});
```

Answer (score 4):

I got another alternative from this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/2bkbx2y3/6/

```
       $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
          function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
        var min = $('#min').datepicker("getDate");
        var max = $('#max').datepicker("getDate");
        var startDate = new Date(data[4]);
        if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
        if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true;}
        if(max == null && startDate >= min) {return true;}
        if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello All Please find attached my code for reference to handle the daterangepicker to filter datatable it will be helpfull for others who are struggling to find the similar solutions.
The below is the universal solution for many datepicker problems please find my attached code for reference.

```css
/*named as styles.css in link tag in html save it the same way to get the result */
#calendar{
        position: center;
        margin-top: 200px;
}

#tabledata{
 margin-top:50px;
 margin-right: 120px;
 margin-left: 120px;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search date from table</title>

<!-- data table -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<!-- date range picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />


<!-- #region datatables files -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
 --><script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<!-- #endregion -->


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">



</head>
<body>

<div id="calender" align="center">

<div id="reportrange" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" align="center">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>


</div>

<div id="tabledata">

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>

</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(function() {
    var start = moment("2019-01-01 12:34:16");
    var end = moment("2020-03-03 10:08:07");

    function cb(start, end) {
      $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
      startDate: start,
      endDate: end,
      ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
      }
    }, cb);//date rangepicker ends here

    cb(start, end);

  }); 
 

   $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    var start = picker.startDate;
    var end = picker.endDate;


      $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      var min = start;
      var max = end;
      var startDate = new Date(data[4]);
      
      if (min == null && max == null) {
        return true;
      }
      if (min == null && startDate <= max) {
        return true;
      }
      if (max == null && startDate >= min) {
        return true;
      }
      if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  ); //external search ends here

  table.draw();
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();


        }); // report range ends here


var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "order": [
      [0, "desc"]
    ],
    lengthChange: false,
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [{
        title: "Name"
      },
      {
        title: "Position"
      },
      {
        title: "Office"
      },
      {
        title: "Extn"
      },
      {
        title: "Start date"
      },
      {
        title: "Salary"
      },
      

    ]
  }); //table var ends here




});// ready function ends here
 


   var dataSet = [
    [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2019/04/25", "$320,800" ],
    [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2019/07/25", "$170,750" ],
    [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562","2020/01/12", "$86,000" ],
    [ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
    [ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
    [ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ],
    [ "Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2020/08/06", "$137,500" ],
    [ "Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900" ],
    [ "Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2020/09/15", "$205,500" ],
    [ "Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600" ],
    [ "Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560" ],
    [ "Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000" ],
    [ "Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600" ],
    [ "Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2020/12/18", "$313,500" ],
    [ "Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750" ],
    [ "Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2020/11/27", "$198,500" ],
    [ "Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000" ],
    [ "Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2020/04/10", "$237,500" ],
    [ "Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2020/10/13", "$132,000" ],
    [ "Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2020/09/26", "$217,500" ],
    [ "Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2019/09/03", "$345,000" ],
    [ "Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2020/06/25", "$675,000" ],
    [ "Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2019/12/12", "$106,450" ],
    [ "Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sydney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600" ],
    [ "Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2020/10/09", "$1,200,000" ],
    [ "Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575" ],
    [ "Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650" ],
    [ "Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2019/06/07", "$206,850" ],
    [ "Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000" ],
    [ "Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2019/08/14", "$163,000" ],
    [ "Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sydney", "2769", "2019/06/02", "$95,400" ],
    [ "Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2020/10/22", "$114,500" ],
    [ "Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2019/05/07", "$145,000" ],
    [ "Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500" ],
    [ "Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2019/03/09", "$324,050" ],
    [ "Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2020/12/09", "$85,675" ]
];
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    } );


} );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {

        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if (dd < 10)
            dd = '0' + dd;

        if (mm < 10)
            mm = '0' + mm;

        today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;


        var Min_temp = '';
        var Max_temp = '';
        if ($('input[name="datefilter"]').val() == '') {
            Min_temp = '01/01/1980';
            Max_temp = today;

        } else {

            var arr_date = $('input[name="datefilter"]').val().split("-");
            Min_temp = arr_date[0].replace(' ', '');
            Max_temp = arr_date[1].replace(' ', '');

        }
        var arr_min = Min_temp.split("/");
        var arr_max = Max_temp.split("/");
        var arr_date = aData[2].split("/");

        var iMin = new Date(arr_min[2], arr_min[0], arr_min[1], 0, 0, 0, 0)
        var iMax = new Date(arr_max[2], arr_max[0], arr_max[1], 0, 0, 0, 0)
        var iDate = new Date(arr_date[2], arr_date[0], arr_date[1], 0, 0, 0, 0)


        if (iMin == "" && iMax == "") {
            return true;
        }
        else if (iMin == "" && iDate < iMax) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (iMin <= iDate && "" == iMax) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (iMin <= iDate && iDate <= iMax) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
);
```

filtre is this

```
  $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        maxDate: today,
        locale: {
            cancelLabel: 'Borrar',
            applyLabel: 'Aceptar',
            daysOfWeek: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
            monthNames: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic']


        }
    });
```

Comment: consider adding some explanation to what your doing and why this answer is correct